# Can't see results of cat command in container

Tags: azure, ubuntu, containers, azure-aks

I am writing a [brigade.js](http://brigade.sh) script to login into azure kubernetes cluster and then fetching tags of an image from acr (azure container registry). 
Code for doing that looks like the following:

```js
var job = new Job("fetch-tag", "microsoft/azure-cli") // pulling img -> microsoft/azure-cli
    job.storage.enabled = true // enables a shared storage b/w different jobs
    job.tasks = [ // list of tasks to be performed or rather the commands to run in the pulled image
      `az login --service-principal -u ${project.secrets.azure_client_id} -p ${project.secrets.azure_client_secret} --tenant ${project.secrets.azure_tenant_id} 2>&1`, // logging into auzre kubernetes cluster
      `az acr repository show-tags -n nxvishal --repository tests | grep -E '\b[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]' -o | tail -1 > /mnt/brigade/share/image_version.txt`, // pulling the tags of tests repo, applying some regex to fiter out unwanted tags and use tail to get one tag from last
      "cat /mnt/brigade/share/image_version.txt 2>&1", // here comes the problem, it doesn't show any output
      "az account show" // shows if i logged in correctly ( and yes i get output for this which is my details which shows I am logged in and code has reached till here) 
    ]
job.run();
```

So I pulled the same image manually (microsoft/azure-cli) and tried the same commands

```
`${project.secrets.azure_client_id} -p ${project.secrets.azure_client_secret} --tenant ${project.secrets.azure_tenant_id} 2>&1`, // I didn't forgot to replace the secrets with appropriate string
`az acr repository show-tags -n nxvishal --repository tests | grep -E '\b[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]' -o | tail -1
```

It shows the output, which is 0.0.4 in this case. But I get no output when I am doing the same with brigade.js

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of your requirements, what you want is to get the last one from the tags which meet your pattern.

Firstly, you need to know the output of the command `az acr repository show-tags -n nxvishal --repository tests | grep -E '\b[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]' -o`. With the test, I think you need to discard the parameter `-o`. So the result will like this:

[image]

Then you can tail the last one, but it will contain a comma behand.

Finally, the whole command here:

```
az acr repository show-tags -n nxvishal --repository tests | grep -E '\b[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]' | tail -1
```

Comment: after some debugging, i reached the conclusion that grep -E '\b[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]' is not working, grep with some other regex would work, but with this particular regex grep command isn't printing out anything

Comment: @VishalTewatia The regex pattern would set according to your tags. You did not show more messages about your tag. I only can give you advice about the question you provide.

Comment: @VishalTewatia If the answer solves the problem with the message you provide in the question, just mark it.